# spring boot opiniated versions - how to override with what we want?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I am having spring project, which is a multi-module project and it is using spring boot (test/pom.xml ; and api/pom.xml )

test/pom.xml has the following boot:

```
<spring.boot.version>2.0.6.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
 </dependency>
```

The versions of jackson-core which comes is --> 2.9.0.7

module's (api) pom.xml (snippet, which shows spring boot dependencies)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

As can be seen,  I am trying to exclude jackson-xxx from spring boot.

Now, I have a jar, say a.jar which has explicit dependencies (with specific versions of jackson -> 2.9.0.8); and that dependency I am adding to my api/pom.xml (not shown above)

Now, when I see which version of jackson-core, jackson-databind which gets resolved to; it takes the version -> 2.9.0.7 (which is part of spring boot; which however I tried to exclude).

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening, and how to make the specific version to be chosen as desired.

Comment: Just add `<jackson.version>version.you.want</jackson.version>` to the `<properties>` section of your pom and please remove the exclusions.

Answer (score 1):

use maven dependency plugin to find out where the dependency comes from:

```
mvn dependencies:list
```

or simple add the explizit version directly to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>                
   <version>2.9.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

This should override the version of spring dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I want to know why in first place we get the version 2.9.0.7 when I excluded from spring boot; and have added a direct dependency (which in turn has the correct version of jackson which I want to use). Can you help me understand this please?

Comment: *why in first place we get the version 2.9.0.7 when I excluded from spring boot* hard to say, maybe there are other dependencies which brings jackson libs with it. Therefore `mvn dependencies:list`, *have added a direct dependency* That is the dependency management, first the  version in the pom will be used, if there is no it will be used from the dependecy at  level 2 than 3 and so on